# Not able to create a repository in Azure DevOps with Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Im trying to create repository in Azure DevOps with HTTP action in Logic App with following steps, but I'm getting "Redirect" error in that step. Please check & guide someone to resolve this. Instead HTTP i also tested with "Send HTTPS request to DevOps" that time getting below error. Please help.

YAML

Copy
"TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: defa4b32-2d1f-4a98-ab6d-a724e20b1a63\r\nDetails: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException,
Steps i followed with HTTP action:User's image

The following steps i was followed with HTTP Action:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am creating the repository in Azure DevOps using PAT as mentioned in this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows).

I have created a PAT and granted below role,

[image]

Take the PAT and encode it to Base64 using below code,

```
$MyPat = 'yourPAT'

$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`:$MyPat"))
```

Then, you need to use $B64Pat in the header while calling the REST API like below,

```
Authorization: Basic <Base64 encoded PAT>
```

**Flow Diagram:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

You can get the Project id using the following URL,

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Organization_Name}/{Project_Name}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0
```

Comment: Hi Ikhtesam Afrin,
I tried as you suggested, but it is not working. Its failing in trigger itself. Kindly provide me any other suggestions.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of how you are trying to do?

Comment: Looks its working now. Much Thanks Ikhtesam Afrin

Comment: Hi Ikhtesam Afrin, I need to create a repository, just team name & just default pipeline with Azure Logic App. Now i have achieved to create repository in Azure DevOps. Can i get the steps to create just team name & just default pipeline, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please open a separate thread for your new requirement by enlisting all the information

Comment: Hi Ikhtesam Afrin, created new thread for that. Please check & guide with steps please. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188344/need-to-create-a-repository-team-name-just-default-pipeline-in-azure-devops-w