# Need to create a repository, team name & just default pipeline in Azure DevOps with Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I Need to create a repository, just team name & just default pipeline in Azure DevOps with Azure Logic App. I have achieved to create a repository in azure DevOps & now stuck to create just team name & just default pipeline. Verified docs & tried to follow few of them & getting unauthorized etc errors are getting. Please someone help to achieve the requirement. Thanks

FYI: Able to create repository with below.
[image]

I have achieved to create a repository in azure DevOps & now stuck to create just team name & just default pipeline.
Verified docs & tried to follow few of them & getting unauthorized etc errors are getting. Please someone help to achieve the requirement. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the doc reference which you have tried?

Comment: Doc reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2#createpipelineparameters 
also the below i have tried

Comment: Doc reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2#createpipelineparameters 
getting Unauthorized error in HTTP Action.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the pipeline and team in the following way-

*Grant the below role for pipeline creation to your PAT,*

[image]

**Workflow for pipeline creation:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=7.2-preview.1
```

[image]

[image]

You can get the repository name and id using  `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0`

**Output:**

[image]

**Team creation**

*Grant the below role to your PAT,*

[image]

**Workflow:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams?api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ikhtesam Afrin. Its working from my end.

Comment: Hi Ikhtesam Afrin, is there a way to create pipeline without depend on repository, bz we need to take repository name & id, so any possible with project/project id  to achieve this.